# What is the time complexity when the iteration goes from 1 to i*i

Tags: c++, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Okay, so I have been wondering what will be the time complexity when the the for loop iterates from 1 to n*n.
Can someone please elaborate the time complexity in the following program???

```
for(i = 1 ; i < n ; i++)
   for(j = 1 ; j < i*i ; j++)
      for(k = 1 ; k < j ; k++)
```

Also, a little twist that confuses:

```
for(i = 1 ; i < n ; i++)
   for(j = 1 ; j < i*i ; j++)
     if(j%i == 0)
       for(k = 1 ; k < j ; k++)
```

Comment: Looks like `O(n^4)` to me

Comment: @Ryan Haining Can you please explain?

Comment: Actually no that's wrong. The outer loop is n, the middle loop is n*n, the innermost loop goes to n^2 as well s so that's n * n^2 * n^2. I don't feel terribly confident about this though.

Answer (score 6):

I think the first one is `O(n^5)`. j is done i^2 times so does k.

```
i -> n
j -> n^2
k -> n^2
```

Thus it is `O(n^5)`.

**EDIT:**
Regarding the second part, maximum number of divisor of a number, N, is less than 2*sqrt(N). Therefore, we can say that upper bound for `for(k=1; k < j; k++)` is `O(sqrt(j)) = O(n)`.

So, the upper bound for the second part is `O(n^4)`

Answer (score 5):

```
i = 1..n
j = 1..i*i
k = 1..j
```

[WolframAlpha says O(n^5)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+i+%3D+1+to+n+of+%28sum+j+%3D+1+to+i*i+of+%28sum+k+%3D+1+to+j+of+1%29%29)

Comment: In the equation your inner loop should not be over k but 1.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Can you please explain an answer for the one with condition???  if(j%i == 0)

Answer (score 4):

The sum to evaluate is

[image]

There is an [equation for polynomial sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula), but the important thing is that the leading term is always one order higher than the polynomial that is being summed. I.e, the answer is O(n^5).

To see the answer directly for loops of type

```
for(i = 1 ; i < n ; i++)
  for(j = 1 ; j < i ; j++)
```

The correct answer can be calculated by just setting the inner loop to be the worst case,

```
for(i = 1 ; i < n ; i++)
  for(j = 1 ; j < n ; j++)
```

which gives directly the answer for this e.g., O(n^2).

In the case with the remainder, the condition effects i^2-i cases out of possible i^2. Hence, the loop is effectively just run i times. The inner loop still runs up to n^2. Hence the overall complexity is  O(n^4).

**Edit**: fixed the answer for the remainder case.

Comment: So, you claim number of divisors of a number (n^2) is O(n^2)

Comment: @smttsp I fixed the answer. I read the code wrong way around first.

Answer (score 3):

For the twisted one what I feel is,
The outer loop (`i` iterator) will iterate `n` times. --> n
The `j` iterator will iterate for 1+2+...n^2 times. So basically making it --> O(n^3)
The `if` condition will hold true for i times each iteration of outer loop (`i` iteration) because `j` goes till `i * i` so the inner loop (`k` iterator) will execute for n times (same as outer loop; `i` iterator). And the final code inside inner loop will execute for 1^3+2^3+3^3....n^3 times. Which makes the total complexity O(n^4).

But I don't feel so confident on this either.